# How to fix a Rails 5 api routing. It keeps generating a base_url of "test.host" in all apps I am creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I want to undo some network settings that keeps generating my app_urls as "test.host" irrespective of the rails app I am running

I was doing a tutorial - http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/.
In Chapter 1, it asked us to add 'pow'/'prax' server to host the Rails 4 app.
I was unable and resulted in even trying 'puma' and eventually after none worked. I just restarted with Rails 5 and I was able to move to the next chapters.

When I progressed further; I hit a stumbling block in testing controllers. My routes_url keeps generating 'test.host' when running.
Controlled experiment. I even recreated another app thinking it was an instance setting and it does the same. So I am sure it is a setting I did.
I've tried uninstalling all settings I did when trying to add a web server manually and I am still unable to resolve it. Please indicate what else I can add to help resolve this issue.

```rb
1) UsersController GET a user returns the info as a hash
     Failure/Error: get user_url(@user), params: { id: @user.id }, format: :json

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/users/7", :controller=>"users", :format=>:json, :id=>7}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET a user 
     Failure/Error: get user_url(@user), params: { id: @user.id }, format: :json

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/users/8", :controller=>"users", :format=>:json, :id=>8}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.09652 seconds (files took 0.7329 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:12 # UsersController GET a user returns the info as a hash
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:17 # UsersController GET a user
```

I expect when running an app my app_url to be "localhost:3000" but the actual output is "test.host" which is failing my routes and I am unable to test any controller.

Comment: Can you please check the config.action_mailer.default_url_options.

You can view this in your environment specific file like config/environments/test.rb(or whichever environment file is generated)

Comment: @AkashP - Hey, I've checked all environment configs. I haven't added any configuration that changes the `action_mailer.default_url_options`